# Extending javascript ( jquery ) library causes TypeError

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to extend javascript `ekko-lighbox` (https://github.com/ashleydw/lightbox) library with my own functionality :

```
import ekkoLightbox from 'ekko-lightbox'

class extendedEkkoLightbox extends jQuery.fn.ekkoLightbox {
    constructor() {
        super()
        const childs = this._$modalHeader[0].children;

        $(childs[0]).replaceWith('');
    }

}

export default extendedEkkoLightbox
```

executing it in code like this :

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const obj = new extendedEkkoLightbox();
});
```

But keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`. Like it wouldnt pass `url` value.

Am I doing something wrong ? How should I extend external libraries ?

Comment: Where is the code that attempts to call `match` and where is the code that receives the URL?

Comment: `jQuery.fn.ekkoLightbox` and `ekkoLightbox` are not same object. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @Scott Marcus It is in `ekko-lightbox` library. But I'm not changing it's functionality so I want it to work just like before.
 
@FisNaN I'm trying to extend library by modifying one of the properties. I thought it is what that class returns.

Comment: @viciousP I didn't ask about that. I asked for you to show the other relevant parts of the code.

Comment: @Scott Marcus I didn't write anything else. If you ask me about code from the library that calls match it's here
`https://pastebin.com/mFkBhRgq`

Comment: @ScottMarcus could you please clarify, what extacly you want me to show ?